# Javascript Regex Replace not working

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I'm trying to replace all characters that are any of the following: `!#` in a javascript string (specifically a URL).

```
href = 'http://example.test/foo/bar#';
href = href.replace('/[\#\!]/g', '');
console.log('href', href);
```

But it doesn't seem to be performing the replacements, even though I tried the regex with various testers and it works with the string.

Comment: regex isn't a string, `'/[\#\!]/g'` => `/[\#\!]/g`

Comment: Also `#` and `!` are not special characters in Javascript regex, you don't have to escape them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have to delete the quotes from **'/[#!]/g'** and it is going to work.